# How do I manage to get a non-null name argument with org.xml.sax.ext.EntityResolver2 resolveEntity method?

Tags: java, xml, sax

In Java SAX processing, I dot not manage to obtain entity reference names from the 
`org.xml.sax.ext.EntityResolver2` resolveEntity method. The name argument is always `null` even if the documentation states that `'name' is never null when invoked by a SAX2 parser`.

Any idea ?

To demonstrate the issue, I have created a Jython 2.5 script. It prints (on my box):

```
Entity Resolver 2 enabled: True
Entity name: None
```

Jython 2.5 script:

```
# Jython
from org.python.core.util import StringUtil
from jarray import array

# Java Standard Edition
from org.xml.sax import *
from org.xml.sax.ext import *
from org.xml.sax.helpers import *
from java.io import ByteArrayInputStream

xml = """\
<!DOCTYPE doc
[<!ENTITY entity SYSTEM "entity-file">
]>
<doc>&entity;</doc>
"""

def empty_source():
    _source = InputSource()
    byte_stream = ByteArrayInputStream(array([], "b"))
    _source.setByteStream(byte_stream)
    return _source

class Handler(EntityResolver2):
    def getExternalSubset(self, name, baseURI):
        return None
    def resolveEntity(self, name, publicId, baseURI, systemId):
        print "Entity name:", name 
        return empty_source()

reader = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader()
enabled = reader.getFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/use-entity-resolver2")
print "Entity Resolver 2 enabled:", enabled 

handler = Handler()
reader.setEntityResolver(handler) 
bytes = StringUtil.toBytes(xml)
byte_stream = ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)
source = InputSource(byte_stream)
reader.parse(source)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a more recent version of Xerces (2.9.1 for example), instead of the "old" one bundled with Java.